# How much certainty is there in adverb "probably"?

Tags: adverbs, modality

[Merriam-webster defines *probably*](http://learnersdictionary.com/definition/probably) as:

> very likely : almost certainly

How much certainty does adverb *probably* actually contain? Examples and contexts are greatly appreciated!

Comment: There is no definitive answer. You can't say "probably" means 80% chance while "likely" means 70% and "maybe" means 40% or any such. I'd quibble with the definition you quote: People often say "probably" meaning "more like than not, over 50% chance", far from "almost certainly". I'd say anything over 50% could be called "probably".

Comment: @Jay, while there is no absolute measurement for "probably", the question can be answered by giving contexts of where it could definitely be used, where it would be borderline, and where it would be inappropriate. Opinion will only come into play on the borderline cases. Otherwise, no one would ever use it.

Comment: I agree with @Jay in that I consider "probable" to mean "more probable than not", i.e. over a 50% chance.

Comment: Yes, you should provide examples and contexts and it would probably be easier to give you an approximate percentage. Besides that is not the only or even best definition of *probably* at MW ([link to MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/probably) ). Look at the **full definition** there.

Comment: @GoDucks I would have given a more completely answer except that at the time I posted, the question was on hold. :-(

Comment: @GoDucks The [learner's dictionary definition](http://learnersdictionary.com/definition/probably) is probably what most learners will use and what this question probably is referring to.

Comment: @Jay Could I twist your arm to go ahead and post your answer now that the question has been re-opened? I hate to see questions like this with only one answer because I think explaining from a few different perspectives would make it clearer.

Comment: @ColleenV Ok. Thanks for the vote of confidence. Now if you down-vote my answer I'll cry.

Comment: @ColleenV I have seen plenty of posts by learners that quote dictionaries other than learner's dictionaries. Most, in fact. The MW I quoted at least has both the 'simple' definition and the 'advanced' one. Interestingly, the Unabridged MW has both and does not give them such labels.

Comment: @Jay Thanks! I'm certain there is a "I probably won't down vote it" joke around here somewhere...

Answer (score 5):

The way I use probably in AmE it means "more likely than not" or I'm 50% or more certain it's true. I would use other words if I was trying to give someone a good idea of how certain I was, for example
**"it's possible (not very certain)"**,
**"fairly sure (somewhat certain, but a little concerned I could be wrong)"**,
**"very certain"**, or
**"almost positive (I think it's true unless something really crazy happens)"**.

I use probably where it's not important to know how certain I am and I just want to say I think something is likely/could be true/could happen. Some examples of using "probably":

> *Alan*: "When will you have this task done?"
>    *Colleen*: "**Probably** some time next week."
>    *Alan*: "Will it be done at the beginning of the week or the end of the week?"
>    *Colleen*: "I'm certain I can have it done by the end of the week if nothing else happens, and I can **probably** get it done sooner if it's very important."
>
> *Alan*: "Why didn't Colleen get that task done?"
>    *Bill*: "**Probably** because she was home with a cold all last week, but she's in the office today so you should ask her to be certain."

Answer (score 3):

There is no definitive answer. You can't say "probably" means 80% chance while "likely" means 70% and "maybe" means 40% or any such.

I'd quibble with the definition you quote: People often say "probably" meaning "more likely than not, over 50% chance", far from "almost certainly". I'd say anything over 50% could be called "probably".

Exactly what the speaker means by it depends on context.

"My wife emptied our bank account and took all her clothes and jewelry and the kids and disappeared. I think I'll wait here by the phone for her to call and let me know where she is." "Dude, she's probably not going to call." It is almost certain, over 95%.

"I like the blue one, but I also really like the green one. This is a tough decision, let me think for minute, but I'll probably end up taking the green one." It's barely more likely than not, maybe 51%.

"There are ten candidates running for this office. I think Jones will probably win." Of the ten, the speaker thinks Jones has the best chance. His chance might be well below 50%, just more than 10%.

If you have really calculated an exact probability, you would quote the probability, you'd say, "We have calculated that there is a 62.4% chance", not use a general word like "probably" or "likely".

Answer (score 1):

Six degrees of probably

> guaranteed *(definitely will happen)*
>   most **probably**
>   very **probably**
>   **probably**
>   some-what **probable**
>   coin toss *(50-50%, maybe, maybe not)*
>   unlikely
>   not **probable**
>   **improbable**
>   no way *(definitely will not happen)*

For example

> Snowfall will **probably** be in the range of 6-10in, **most probably** causing delays in commuting

meaning

> if there is heavy snowfall it **almost certainly** will cause traffic delays (it may not cause delays if everyone stays at home).

Traffic delays will happen with more certainty since the occurrence is conditioned on there being significant snow in the first place.